# COMPILATION ERROR error: static_assert failed "Something went wrong. Please report this issue to the github

Tags: smart-contract, deferred-transactions, eosio-cpp

Getting an error when the code reaches this particular function.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?
**Kindly Note this is Deferred transaction**

Please ask if anything else is required from my side.

````
void mainloan::checkdaily(uint64_t loan_id){
  require_auth(_self);

  auto itr = loan_table.find(loan_id);
  auto borrower=itr->borr_name;
  time_point tday;

  eosio::transaction t {};
  t.actions.emplace_back(
    permission_level(_self,"active"_n),
    _self,
    "calipd"_n, //fuction for calculating interest per day on principle amount 
    std::make_tuple(itr));
    t.delay_sec=20;//86400;
    t.send(now(),_self);
    eosio::print("transaction sent.");
    defer_table.emplace(get_self(),[&](auto &df){
      df.df_id = defer_table.available_primary_key();
      df.transaction_date=tday;
    });

}```




 error: static_assert failed "Something went wrong. Please report this issue to the github along with the structure you're reflecting."
    static_assert(
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `std::make_tuple(itr)` to `std::make_tuple(*itr)`. The type of itr is const_iterator and it's not serializable.

Comment: how do i get to know about all this, bcoz even in documentation it was given as it is

Comment: Block.one is improving documentation widely. You can wait until it is done or I don't think there is another clue except for code itself.

Comment: This is more of a basic cpp convention than something block one needs to document specifically. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/ the ITR is a pointer and the * is a dereference operator that gives access to the actual contents of the variable contained in the memory referenced by the pointer. By the way, you can tell ITR is a pointer by your use of the -> operator on it.